# Segmentation fault of pointer&char

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

Im trying to make the program that extract filenames by inputing some folderpath.

The outcome is fine, but the problem is at the end of outcome, there's some segmentation fault that i cant figure out.

Here's what I wrote in.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main() {

char folderpath;
printf("enter the path : \n");
scanf("%s",&folderpath);



DIR   *d;
struct dirent *dir;
d = opendir(&folderpath);
if (d)
{
    while((dir= readdir(d)) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", dir->d_name);
    }
    closedir(d);

};

return 0;
}
```

And, result is like

```
enter the path : /Users/gui/Desktop/extract/extract
.
..
main
main.c
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Sorry for asking really simple question like this, which I tried hard to figure out but I cant.

Thanks for reading this question.
Best Regard.

Comment: run it under a debugger, it will show you which line is failing

Comment: folderpath only allocates a single character of space, and you're trying to read the whole string into it.  Change the definition to `char folderpath[100];` or something with enough space.  Then get rid of the `&` in the scanf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `scanf` with the `%s` format specifier, it expects a pointer to an array of characters.  What you're passing is the address of a single character.  So it writes past the memory location of that variable into whatever happens to be next to it.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need pass a character array to `scanf`:

```
char folderpath[256];
printf("enter the path : \n");
scanf("%s",folderpath);

...

d = opendir(folderpath);
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do this

```
char folderpath;
printf("enter the path : \n");
scanf("%s",&folderpath);
```

You have reserved space for one character. YOu need

```
char folderpath[MAX_PATH];
printf("enter the path : \n");
scanf("%s",&folderpath);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare char foldrpath only one byte of memory is allocated that is you can store only one character. When you try to store more than one byte it results in to segmentation fault (access of the memory location out side your process space in this case). So try to use an array like char folderpath[MAXFOLDERLENGTH]  else you can get the contiguous block of bytes by calling malloc like
char *foldrpath = (char*) malloc(MAXFOLDERLENGTH),  this malloc assigns the memory in Heap area where as the former declaration will give you memory allocated in stack area.  Hope this helps